# Correct but not displaying result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, laravel

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM one_chat WHERE chat_email = '{$get_mail}' && chat_email = '{$session_email}' ";
```

> Query is CORRECT, but not displaying result on AND condition, if use OR operator then both conditions becomes true and displays both data! Why so disguisting!!!

Comment: what is the value in this variables ($get_mail ,$session_email ) ?

Comment: $get_mail is for $_GET method and $session_email is for $_SESSION global variable

Comment: ok , make var_dump($get_mail ,$session_email) , and show to us the output

Comment: Only for $_GET method var_dump showing NULL

Answer (score 0):

i think use this and check if it gives any result

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM one_chat WHERE chat_email = '{$get_mail}' AND chat_email = '{$session_email}' ";
```

basically try to replace && with AND

Comment: i think that you must change **&&** to **OR**. In your query you will check in  chat_email equals this and also chat_email equals that. this can only give a result if  '{$get_mail}' AND  '{$session_email}' have the same value

Comment: Let me remind you one thing that firstly, I used $_GET method from 1st page then I used this with ajax in second page which gets data from third page. In other words, I used a single 'email' in three pages.

Comment: insert a echo after **$sql= "SELECT ...."** and show us the output

Comment: SELECT * FROM one_chat WHERE chat_email = '' AND chat_email = 'cybersite159@gmail.com'

Comment: I can correct this with PHP but I want to use it with AJAX because in messenger page doesn't want to be refreshed!

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() becomes FALSE why so!

Answer (score 0):

according to the comments , this var value ( $get_mail ) is null , and you try to select data with condition this ( chat_email = '{$get_mail}' AND chat_email = '{$session_email}') ,
you need chat_email to be null and another value come from session .
you can change condition to "or"

or , if the both variables have the same value in your business, you can do that :-

```
$email = !empty($get_mail) ? $get_mail : $session_email;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM one_chat WHERE chat_email = '{$email}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM one_chat WHERE chat_email = COALESCE('{$get_mail}','{$session_email}')";
```